# Manual Configuration of DataSource Based on Spring Environment in ApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to create a database-driven Spring PropertySource that will read properties that would normally be in `application.properties` or an externalized property file defined with `@PropertySource`. Before anyone asks, the "why" is because that's how I've been told to do it.

It seems like the best way to do this is to create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` that creates the `PropertySource` and adds it to the Environment:

```java
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(source);
```

At this point, beans have not been loaded into the application context. This means I can't just grab the DataSource bean from said context.

Unfortunately, the datasource configuration is in application.properties (the file isn't going away, but MOST properties are moving to the database. Datasource configuration stays.). So, somehow I need to configure a datasource for one-time use.

Oracle provides the UCPDataSource class specifically for Spring Boot, but somehow I need to manually bind an instance of it to values in the Environment (a task that is normally done in a BeanPostProcessor).

Anyone have any ideas?